# Can Atmel Studio 6 Simulator simulate SPI?

Tags: atmel-studio

I am trying to do PAL composite video output with Arduino Nano. I am using Atmel Studio 6, not the Arduino IDE. I am sending out the picture data via SPI. On the TV I could not see the text I tried to produce, so I tried to run my program in the Atmel Studio simulator (to use it as a logic analyzer). But in the resulting stimuli file I also do not see the MOSI pin changing.

I am using the A0 pin (PORTC bit 0) to send out the sync signal, that appears correctly in the output .stim file: PORTC changes exactly at the right time. But PORTB does not change at all.

My program can definitely be buggy, but that is another topic... the question is, **can Atmel Studio Simulator simulate the SPI** at all?

Comment: How is this even related to Arduino?

Comment: An IDE doesn't simulate SPI. I don't understand your question. `My program can definitely be buggy` - without posting any code your question is very vague.

Answer (score 1):

No Atmel Studio cannot simulate SPI.

The fact that you are using SPI makes me think that you are using the MAX7456 IC or even the [SparkFun On Screen Display Breakout](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/9168) which uses this same IC.

You can generate composite video just by using a few resistors and an Arduino.

I have found a number of sites on Google who have used the Arduino to output PAL composite video to display the Pong game on an old TV.

- http://searle.hostei.com/grant/AVRPong/index.html
- http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-recreate-the-classic-pong-game-using-arduino/
- http://www.instructables.com/id/2-player-Pong-using-Arduino/
- http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=8708.0
- http://apcmag.com/arduino-project-7-build-a-retro-gamebox.htm/
- http://electronics.divinechildhighschool.org/Home/electronics-spring-2012-1/arduino-pong

Comment: Arduino PAL output is bad, takes a LOT of processing power and doing overlays is even harder. Using MAX7456 is just a lot of easier, although you might have a few other problems with it.